# file download and open through VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to download the Excel file attached to html via Excel vba and output it in Excel sheet. This homepage is a list of the current status of the box office that has been popular in Korean movie theaters.

http://www.kobis.or.kr/kobis/business/stat/boxs/findFormerBoxOfficeList.do?loadEnd=0&searchType=search&sMultiMovieYn=&sRepNationCd=&sWideAreaCd=

### Attached file is Excel. I understand that downloading can be done using the click method through Internet search. However, an alert window appears during downloading of the file, and the date is inserted in the name of the Excel file to be downloaded. As a beginner in Excel VBA it is very difficult. So I left this question, and what logic would it be useful to implement to spread this file on an Excel sheet? I am a beginner in Excel VBA so if you give me a detailed answer, it will be really helpful.

```
<p class = "btn_regi">
<a href="#none" class="btn_type01" onclick="chkform('excel'); return false ;"> 
<strong> Excel </ strong> </a>
</ p>
```

The following logic I have coded myself until dawn. However, the logic was too inefficient and the results did not work so I asked for help.

```
Sub program_()

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        Dim bridge As String

        Dim WinHttp As New WinHttpRequest
        Dim sResponse As String, html As New HTMLDocument, hStructure As Object, hTable As HTMLTable

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set WinHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

        Dim Url As String
        Url = "http://www.kobis.or.kr/kobis/business/stat/boxs/findFormerBoxOfficeList.do?"

        Dim p1 As String 'parameter
        Dim v1 As String
        Dim p2 As String
        Dim v2 As String
        Dim p3 As String
        Dim v3 As String
        Dim p4 As String
        Dim v4 As String
        Dim p5 As String
        Dim v5 As String
        Dim v As Integer
        Dim g As Integer

        bridge = "&"
        p1 = "loadEnd="
        v1 = 0
        p2 = "searchType="
        v2 = "search"
        p3 = "sMultiMovieYn="
        v3 = ""
        p4 = "sRepNationCd="
        v4 = ""
        p5 = "sWideAreaCd="
        v5 = ""


            With WinHttp

                .Open "get", "" & Url & p1 & v1 & bridge & p2 & v2 & bridge & p3 & v3 & bridge & p4 & v4 & bridge & p5 & v5 & ""
                .SetRequestHeader "Referer", "http://www.kobis.or.kr/kobis/business/stat/boxs/findFormerBoxOfficeList.do?"
                .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                .Send
                .WaitForResponse ': DoEvents

                sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)

            Dim hforms As HTMLFormElement

            With html
                .body.innerHTML = sResponse
                sResponse = ""


                Set hTable = .getElementsByClassName("boardList03")(0)
            End With

            Dim Arr0() As Variant
            Dim tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, r As Long, c As Long
            r = 0
            With ws
                Set tRow = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")

                ReDim Arr0(tRow.Length - 1, 10)
                For Each tr In tRow
                    r = r + 1
                    Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")

                Dim j As Integer

                    c = 1
                    For Each td In tCell

                        If td.ID = "td_rank" Then
                        Arr0(r - 1, 0) = td.innerText
                        End If

                        If td.ID = "td_movie" Then
                        Arr0(r - 1, 1) = td.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText
                        End If

                        If td.ID = "td_openDt" Then
                        Arr0(r - 1, 2) = td.innerText
                        End If

                        If td.ID = "td_salesAcc" Then
                        Arr0(r - 1, 3) = td.innerText
                        End If

                        If td.ID = "td_audiAcc" Then
                        Arr0(r - 1, 4) = td.innerText
                        End If

                        If td.ID = "td_scrnCnt" Then
                        Arr0(r - 1, 5) = td.innerText
                        End If

                        If td.ID = "td_showCnt" Then
                        Arr0(r - 1, 6) = td.innerText
                        End If

                        c = c + 1
                    Next td

                Next tr

                Dim k As Integer
                Dim i As Integer

                k = 0
                For i = LBound(Arr0, 1) To UBound(Arr0, 1)

                                           .Cells(2 + k + g, 2) = Arr0(i, 0)
                                           .Cells(2 + k + g, 3) = Arr0(i, 1)

                                           .Cells(2 + k + g, 4) = Arr0(i, 2)
                                           .Cells(2 + k + g, 5) = Arr0(i, 3)
                                           .Cells(2 + k + g, 6) = Arr0(i, 4)
                                           .Cells(2 + k + g, 7) = Arr0(i, 5)
                                           .Cells(2 + k + g, 8) = Arr0(i, 6)
                        k = k + 1
                Next i
            End With

        Erase Arr0

        Set tRow = Nothing: Set tCell = Nothing: Set tr = Nothing: Set td = Nothing
        Set hforms = Nothing
        Set hTable = Nothing


        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        End Sub
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice someone writes the code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help.

Comment: SORRY, KEN White..I've already experienced a lot of failures and I've been asking you for help. I do not attach my case after trial and error, so I think you misunderstood. So I tried to attach the failed logic again. I would appreciate it if you understood it well after many failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just grab the table by its id and then loop the table rows and table cells within rows.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, hTable As HTMLTable
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://www.kobis.or.kr/kobis/business/stat/boxs/findFormerBoxOfficeList.do?loadEnd=0&searchType=search&sMultiMovieYn=&sRepNationCd=&sWideAreaCd="

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set hTable = .document.getElementById("table_former")

        WriteTable hTable, 1, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        .Quit
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub


Public Sub WriteTable(ByVal hTable As HTMLTable, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)

    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim tSection As Object, tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, r As Long, c As Long, tBody As Object
    r = startRow
    With ws
        Dim headers As Object, header As Object, columnCounter As Long
        Set headers = hTable.getElementsByTagName("th")
        For Each header In headers
            columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
            .Cells(startRow, columnCounter) = header.innerText
        Next header
        startRow = startRow + 1
        Set tBody = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
        For Each tSection In tBody               'HTMLTableSection
            Set tRow = tSection.getElementsByTagName("tr") 'HTMLTableRow
            For Each tr In tRow
                r = r + 1
                Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                c = 1
                For Each td In tCell             'DispHTMLElementCollection
                    .Cells(r, c).Value = td.innerText 'HTMLTableCell
                    c = c + 1
                Next td
            Next tr
        Next tSection
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**References (VBE> Tools > References):**

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library
2. Microsoft Internet Controls